# Обработка данных перед сохранением админ панели Django

Tags: python, django

Есть простая модель

`class Job(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)`

Необходимо реализовать обработку введённых данных  с формы в админке перед сохранением. Логичнее, наверно, сделать отдельную форму и вьюху для обработки, но если всё таки необходимо форму оставить в админ панели, то как можно реализовать обработку?
В модели есть ImageField, мне нужно обрезать картинку и только потом записывать в базу для дальнейшего вывода в шаблон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете переопределить метод [ModelAdmin.save_model(request, obj, form, change)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).